# APNS Background handling for badge counter

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I am integrated APNS in my app, The requirement is to maintain notification count    when app in background. For example we got notification in background in there is key **counter count** , i,e changing dynamic in every notification, Can it possible to handle in iOS when app is background or app has forcefully closed.

Answer (score 7):

This is the APNS payload from back end server.

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You got your emails.",
        "badge" : 9,
        "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
    },
    "acme1" : "bar",
    "acme2" : 42
}
```

1. The value for key **badge** is automatically considered as badge count.On ios app side no need to calculate or handle the count.
2. In above example **9** is the badge count.So your app icon will show **9.**
3. **NOTE** While your app is close u can't handle badges on your own.Thats why we are using badge key from **APNS Payload**
4. For better clarification about notification see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html)

**EDIT:** if you want to reduce the badge count on your own.Decrement the count and update it yourself.as follows

```
NSInteger numberOfBadges = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber
numberOfBadges -=1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:numberOfBadges];
```

or else make the count to **0**, so that badge icon will be disappeared.Add the below code in ** applicationDidBecomeActive**

```
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

Comment: nice effort @gokul

Comment: @gokul can it possible without clicking on notification in background the badge counter updated.

Comment: @ Bunty Madan can it possible without clicking on notification in background the badge counter updated.

Comment: When i am clicking in notification tray the app will open and badge counter updated, Without click can it possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: @CharlePrabhat no, as per your requirement you have to introduce server or another option is every time send 1 as badge counter from the server and clear it once you open the application.

Comment: No Charle you can't handle badge count without touching the notification without having backend help.

Comment: @Charle image added by Bunty Madan shows the entire process.it helps you to understand about push notification.

Answer (score 3):

For managing the notification counter you have to setup functionality at server. lets take `Facebook` example if you are not reading the new notification the counter keep increase by one and once you click on notification it comes back to zero. so whenever you read new notification it also managed on server side whether is user opened it or not.

lets say there are `3` notifications user di't see than for next one counter will be `4`.

And once your receive the count from server with update, handle it like if all updates are viewed application badge counter set to `0`

this is my understanding as i have implemented the same in my `iOS` application if anyone has any good solution. please suggest.

I hope this picture(source google) will give the complete understanding.

[image]

Comment: When i am dong this its working correct, -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1; 
} but my problem is that i am unable to update badge counter when app is forcefully closed.Like [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey: @"badgecount"] intValue];
but unable to identify the methods where i have to put this code.Please help thanks

Comment: In your case on each notification you are increasing the count by one, let's if the application is in terminated state then? this function will not get call. only `badgeCount` whatever you are getting from the server will be visible on app icon. so in that case you have to manage it from server so that server will send you the correct count.

Comment: @CharlePrabhat please accept the answer if it helped.